# What is the best data model to represent mathematical range (in database, xml, json...)?

Tags: database, math, xml, data-modeling

For example,

> greater or equal to 50 and smaller than 100 (>=50 && < 100)
>
> smaller than 10 or greater than 40 (<10 || >40)

I have been thinking about how to represent mathematical range in a file and database, the range may be input by non programmer and I need to keep the input simple, but at another side, it also need to keep the input easy to convert to data and easy to check error input e.g.: `<10 || >100` seems the most simple but it is harder for me to parse the string to get the data, also need to consider input format error

I have been considering some input methods, using >=50 && < 100 as example, which is in key value form:

1. Using one string to represent whole range:

   ```
   <rangeInString>=50 && < 100</rangeInString>
   ```
2. Separate two strings, one represent lower bound and another one represent upper bound, then parse each string in program:

   ```
   <lowerBound> >=50 </lowerBound>
   <upperBound> <100 </upperBound>
   ```
3. Separate lower and upper bound, also separate the sign from number:

   ```
   <lowerBound>
     <sign> >= </sign>
     <data>50</data>
   </lowerBound>
   <upperBound>
     <sign> < </sign>
     <data>100</data>
   </upperBound>
   ```
4. Separate lower bound and upper bound,also separate sign, and also separate the case that if includes the equal condition:

   ```
   <lowerBound>
     <sign> > </sign>
     <isIncludeEqual>true</isIncludeEqual>
     <data>50</data>
   </lowerBound>
   <upperBound>
     <sign> < </sign>
     <isIncludeEqual>false</isIncludeEqual>
     <data>100</data>
   </upperBound>
   ```
5. auto detect using `&&` or `||`, e.g. :>= A with < B,if A < B, must be `&&` e.g. (`>= 50 && <100`), otherwise it is `||` e.g. (`>= 100 || <50`):

   ```
   <A>
     <sign> > </sign>
     <isIncludeEqual>true</isIncludeEqual>
     <data>50</data>
   </A>
   <B>
     <sign> < </sign>
     <isIncludeEqual>false</isIncludeEqual>
     <data>100</data>
   </B>
   ```
6. Use a field "isAnd" to separate >=50 && < 100 (true) and <=50 || > 100 (false) instead of using field sign "<" and ">" :

   ```
   <lowerBound>
     <isIncludeEqual>true</isIncludeEqual>
     <data>50</data>
   </lowerBound>
   <upperBound>
     <isIncludeEqual>false</isIncludeEqual>
     <data>100</data>
   </upperBound>
   <isAnd>true</isAnd>
   ```
7. other data model...

I need to consider somethings:

1. easy for non programmer to input
2. easy to convert or parse to data into program
3. easy to check error, for example,parse string increase the complexity of converting data and checking incorrect format, also there may have other incorrect format,e.g.: `<=50 && >100` should not be valid, I may allow auto detect using `&&` or `||` by the sign of input, but it may increase the complexity of the code

Comment: "the range may be input by non-programmer" means that [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com) may be involved. After all, every single assumptions we programmers might make about the software users might well be wrong/invalidated.

Answer (score 7):

If you're working solely with integer ranges, you're probably over-thinking the problem. All you need to store is the lower bound and the upper bound, and use a fixed rule about whether the bounds are inclusive. For example, Python ranges tend to use a half-closed interval, so that:

```
range(5,10)
```

Is what mathematicians would write as:

```
[5, 10)         # interval notation
5 <= x < 10     # inequality notation
5, 6, 7, 8, 9   # list notation
```

This is easily encoded into XML, JSON, or database values. E.g.:

```
<range low="5" high="10"/>   # XML
[5, 10]                      # simple list (brackets are data delimiters, 
                                            not mathematical interval notation)
{ "low": 5, "high": 10 }     # JSON fragment
```

It's very easy to take a fixed set of rules, which seems very rigid, and get back whatever you want. For example, if you really wanted the 10 high bound included, then don't provide lots of additional flexibility machinery and complexity (which costs extra data encoding bytes, testing requirements, and code complexity). Just encode it as:

```
<range low="5" high="11"/>  # XML

range(5, 11)                # Python
```

If you don't like the asymmetry of a half-open interval, there's no reason you can't choose a fully closed / inclusive interval, or any other option (i.e., fully open interval, or half-open at the start interval). The trick is choosing a rule that is consistent throughout, and is most consistent / convenient with your programming environment.

This representation nicely handles finite ranges. It's very compact, can be implemented in a very performance-efficient way, and if you'd like extended operations, can be easily implemented as a neat class in Java, Python, and many other languages.

You also seem to want to represent discontinuous, infinite sets such as `x < 10 ∪ x > 40`. Those are generally not considered "ranges" by most programming languages / systems, and indeed aren't even intervals in the mathematical sense. But they're obviously interesting adjacent concepts to consider--though it will add notable complexity to the implementation.

For example. your disjoint set can be specified as a "multi-range," a combination of individual ranges:

```
<union>
    <range low="-Infinity" high="10"/>
    <range low="41" high="Infinity"/>
</union>
```

Now you've had to add handling for abstract values (negative and positive infinity) as well as a set combining operation (`union`) as the multi-range constructor. But, I've read the source of a number of numerical set and multi-range modules, and this is actually how many of them do it.

When you get going down this path of generalizing from individual intervals / ranges to multi-interval, multi-range sets, you may also start to generalize the set operations into other constructive formulations. If you do `union`, why not `intersection`, `difference`, and `symmetric-difference` as well? Your disjoint range could also be specified alternatively as:

```
<difference>
    <range low="-Infinity" high="Infinity"/>
    <range low="10" high="41"/>
</difference>
```

But you've got to be careful, because the more operations and the more complexity, the greater chance of errors creeping in.

Comment: I believe the OP also wants to implement the range "all numbers other than 0 .. 9" in this data structure.

Comment: Good catch. "All numbers other than 0 .. 9" is not actually a range, but OP does want to represent it, and it's certainly a reasonable desire. Amended answer to address.

Comment: The set `x<10 || x>40` could also be represented as `not [10, 40]`, introducing just a negation instead of a union operator and abstract values. I believe the negated range is also closer to what non-mathematical people think about in such cases.

Comment: +1, but I would rather not mix strings with numbers in `low` and `high`. Simply letting attributes unset, or null, could represent unboundedness: `{low:"45"}` means `[45,∞[`. Also, I would maybe use another type of range tag and define an empty range too instead of hacks like `{low:"1",high:"0"}`. </bikeshedding>

Comment: I think the "multi-range" or a "range set" of isolated ranges is the way to go. Ranges of a range set being isolated (not overlapping or having at least one point between them) is important to avoid having many representation for the same range set. Boolean operations should probably be defined only on range sets, not on ranges, because ranges themselves do not work as a base for a boolean algebra: a union of ranges is not always a range etc. Range sets however work perfectly: any boolean operation with range sets results in a range set.

Comment: @COMEFROM Boolean operators on sets is probably the wrong way to go.  Set operators on a set of ranges however... [∪](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)), [⊆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#The_symbols_.E2.8A.82_and_.E2.8A.83), [∩](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) - that's another matter.  While those symbols may be a bit confusing at first, representing the ideas behind them is less confusing than overloading the meaning of bit or Boolean operations.

Comment: @MichaelT: I really didn't mean overloading the usual two-value boolean operators of some programming language (or, and, not) but rather just implementing the corresponding set operators (union, intersection, complement) just like you proposed. I used the word "boolean" in a broader sense: [mathematically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29) speaking set operators are actually boolean operators when the domain is right.

Answer (score 3):

In XSD, ranges are represented using the four element minInclusive, maxInclusive, minExclusive, maxExclusive, for example

```
<xs:restriction>
  <minExclusive="10"/>
  <maxInclusive="20"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

In my experimental FtanML design I took that approach and simplified it to four attributes le, lt, ge, gt:

```
<integer gt=10 le=20>
```

If we take a pure data modelling approach, the range has two properties, a min and a max, each of which may be absent, and each of which, if present, comprises an integer (the limit), and a boolean (indicating whether a value equal to the limit is permitted). That might suggest a cleaner design is:

```
<range>
  <min limit="10" inclusive="true"/>
  <max limit="20" inclusive="false"/>
</range>
```

But at this point it becomes clear that the best design depends on what you are trying to optimise.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the maths involved. Do you want the set to be closed under the operations you use? Most definitely yes, otherwise it won't be useful. Then you'd have to implement: + and - infinities, open vs. closed endpoints, an empty set, and multi-interval ranges.

Database storage can proceed via a custom datatype (you'd have to port your business logic to the DB for sane retrieval, comparison, sorting, and indexing), or by a separate table where each atomic range is stored in 5 attributes (ID, left bound type, left bound value, right bound type, right bound value).

In-program storage has to have records using the same items, but this time the burden of indexing is on you - you have to make retrieval/lookup efficient (O(1) is the best thing to have) to be able to process large disjoint ranges and algebraic/set operations on them.

Source: own experience implementing a set ops library for in-house use.

Answer (score -1):

You need lower and higher bounds, and which of these two are *inclusive*.

```
<lower inclusive="true">-50</lower>
<higher inclusive="false">100</higher
```

would be the range `[-50,100)`.